# Display my app in the UIActionSheet of the default Photos app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My app is registered for certain file types, images + pdf etc, following the guidelines
provided by Apple. My app does show up("open in" option) when pdf files are encountered
in mobile-safari, but it is not the case with image files. In the default "Photos"
app provided by apple, the "open in" option does not show up. Probably this is because
it is implemented without using the document interaction controller. But is there any
way to make my app appear in the UIActionSheet button, which appears at the bottom left
corner ?

I do not want to use the UIImagePickerController for choosing the saved images.

Comment: for that you need to add one key CFBundleDocumentTypes in info.plist check in apple documentation

Comment: @Leena : What do you mean by adding one key ? As I stated in the question, I have registered appropriately for the required file types. Can you please explain what you meant ?

Comment: Is any body out there to help ?

Comment: I never saw any app that could add itself to this actionSheet. Based on that I would say it's not possible though I don't know this as a fact.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you can do is add this key-value pair to your info.plist file. iPhone saves pictures in ".JPG", so that's what you should put as the file type.

(if it doesn't appear in Photos action sheet, that means that Apple doesn't want it to appear. You'll just have to hope that some day...)

p.s. more information and detailed instructions here:
[Registering the File Types Your App Supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)